# Linux install old version of gimp

Tags: linux, gimp

I am using Fedora 17 64 bit.  I would like to install the 2.6 version of gimp (current version is 2.8).

I can't just use `yum install gimp` because that will install 2.8

I think gimp ruined the Ctrl-S save functionality by forcing users to save to .xvf format and nothing else.  The gimp forums clearly state they are unapologetic about this.

So that means to crop an image and save it out goes from two clicks: <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> and <kbd>Ok</kbd> to about 9 clicks.  File->export->click your file extension->pick your options->confirm your options->export the file->close the window to confirm you want to delete the file you just saved.

To gimp's credit, version 2.6 is rock solid software.  How can I get Gimp 2.6 to run on my Fedora 17?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a work around by using wine emulator with the 2.6 version of gimp.  Here are the steps I followed:

**Install wine:**

```
sudo yum install wine
```

**Grab the 2.6 version from oldapps.com**

Get file `gimp-2.6.7-i686-setup.exe` from link: http://www.oldapps.com/gimp.php?old_gimp=46?download

**Run the installer in the emulator**

```
wine gimp-2.6.7-i686-setup.exe
```

**Follow the install window's directions**

Click next, next, and install.  Gimp should be running and you can work with it at this point.

**How to hook gimp to an icon launcher**

Take a look around where it was installed:

```
cd /home/youruser/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/GIMP-2.0/bin
```

In there you see:

```
gimp-2.6.exe
```

Run:

```
wine gimp-2.6.exe
```

And the program runs like a charm.  You could attach it to an icon or key combination to start it fast.  Thanks wine developers!

Answer (score 1):

You can download version 2.6 of Gimp [here](http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/). I would recommend downloading the latest version of 2.6 which would be `gimp-2.6.12.tar.bz2`, because I would assume that would be the most stable.

Be sure to uninstall the current version of Gimp, and then install this version. To install, do the following:

```
% tar xvfz gimp-2.6.x.tar.gz   # unpack the sources
% cd gimp-2.6.x                # change to the toplevel directory
% ./configure                  # run the `configure' script
% make                         # build GIMP
% make install                 # install GIMP
```

If you need more details, you can read about building from source [here](http://www.gimp.org/source/). The file `INSTALL` in the .tar.gz file also has lots of information about installing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the answer in a more organic way: for problem like this one I see 4 family of solution:

1. **Install 2 versions** of the program on the same system (it's more cosy to install e.g. gimp 2.8 for all the users and additionally gimp 2.6 for your particular user). When you need you can always use the updated version. Note that this solution is usually adopted to have the *updated-but-not-stable* version of your needed program together with the stable one.
2. **Freeze** the system version installed on your system to the particular version (gimp 2.6).
3. **Use settings** and keyboard shortcuts of the program to replay the behaviour you want.
4. Install a different version that runs on an **emulated system** (wine or Virtual Machine).

More in details:

1. Following what suggested by Adam you can download the subversion you want from [here](http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/) and install in local path specifyng when you execute `./configure` script the option ***--prefix=PATH*** instead of the default /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/man, etc.

   ```
    tar xvfj gimp-2.6.12.tar.bz2   # unpack the sources
    cd gimp-2.6.12                 # change to the toplevel directory  
    ./configure --prefix=PATH      # run the `configure' script  
    make                           # build GIMP  
    make install                   # install GIMP
   ```
2. *Freeze*. I think you can use yum too. Try installing the *downgrade plugin*, if not yet in your system, and *yum-versionlock* to freeze it:

   ```
    yum install yum-allowdowngrade            # if not installed
    yum --allow-downgrade install gimp-2.6    # you can be more specific too...
    yum install yum-versionlock               # if not installed
    yum versionlock gimp                      # if you want to freeze
   ```

   To have the full list of all the version you can use
        yum --showduplicates list gimp
   For the Ubuntu users it is a little shorter (`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>`)
3. If you don't really want to use *Ctrl+Shift+E* but you want to try a workaround,
   you can keep gimp 2.8 and change some settings:

   - Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts.
   - Search for the text "overwrite".
   - Click on (File-overwrite) *Disabled*, it will be changed to *New Accelerator*.
   - Press *Ctrl+S* to (re)assign this shortcut.
   - Confirm the substitution with a click of the *Reassign shortcut* button. and save it.
     Now with *Ctrl+S* you can save the png o jpg file more quickly. 
     It remains the annoyance to ignore the modification in the .xvf file when you close... 
     life is not perfect I know :)
4. You can use the windows version under wine or Virtualbox, maybe it's better to download it from the main site of gimp [here](http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/windows/) and to take the last version ( gimp-2.6.12-i686-setup.exe)